# How to set and get the relationship records with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

The documentation very clearly explains how to define the relationships, such as the one-to-many:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

But it doesn't give any examples how I would go about setting or retrieving the related `children`. How could I for example query a `Parent` from the database and retrieve a collection of its children and then add or remove some? Is there a resource with examples for each relationship?

Comment: Here're some pointers: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#working-with-related-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#working-with-related-objects) from the documentation the short answer is that when the relationship is represented by a single object, like here:

```
class Child:
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

assigning an object of class Parent to it will suffice:

```
parent = Parent()
child.parent = parent
```

and `parent = child.parent` will retrieve the parent object. According to the guide this occurs due to *attribute on-change events and is evaluated in Python*. When the relationship is represented by a collection, *various collection types, such as sets and dictionaries, are possible but the default is a Python list*:

```
class Parent:
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")
```

So here you can assign a list of Child objects:

```
parent.children = [
    Child(),
    Child()
]
```

Or retrieve a list of objects from the `children` property and modify it.